# Python Script doesnt start, something involving a 'subprocess'

Tags: python, subprocess, simplehttpserver, basehttpserver

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import os
class randomiser(self):
    def random():
        print "hi"
class MyRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.send_header("Content-length", len("hi"))
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write("hi")

PORT = 8002

Handler = MyRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), MyRequestHandler())

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

This just randomly decides to take a crap on itself, error:

http://creeper9207.com/error.PNG

other info:
Windows 10 beta Build 9926
python 2.7.9
errors in both idle and terminal, terminal is too quick to see

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, Problem found i was using Simple instead of Base